# Keep new line where grep is output

Tags: linux, for-loop, grep

When I run `ls` I see the following. I want to delete all instances of `Screen Shot..`

```
10-15
BashStorage
blah.csv
LockScreen.app
NetsuiteBFN
Screen Shot 2017-10-26 at 11.09.08 AM.png
Screen Shot 2017-11-02 at 12.24.13 PM.png
Screen Shot 2017-11-10 at 9.20.33 AM.png
Screen Shot 2017-11-10 at 9.21.29 AM.png
Screen Shot 2017-11-20 at 10.26.24 AM.png
Screen Shot 2017-11-20 at 10.29.18 AM.png
Screen Shot 2017-11-20 at 10.30.40 AM.png
Screen Shot 2017-11-20 at 10.31.55 AM.png
Screen Shot 2017-11-20 at 10.34.11 AM.png
Screen Shot 2017-11-20 at 10.55.34 AM.png
Screen Shot 2017-11-20 at 10.56.44 AM.png
Screen Shot 2017-11-20 at 10.56.54 AM.png
Screen Shot 2017-11-20 at 10.59.20 AM.png
finalResourceUrls.txt
good
lockScreen
lockScreen.zip
ls.txt
x
```

`ls | grep -F 'Screen Shot'` returns only the screenshot entries each on a **new line**

The following code tries to find the file `screen` then `shot` for `$i`
`for i in $(ls | grep -F "Screen Shot"); do rm $i; done`

and fails because it uses a `space` as delimiter

I also observed that grep will print new lines when stdout is the terminal but when I redirect to a file, the new lines are maintained
`(ls | grep -F "Screen Shot") > shots.txt`

However, if I set the output to a variable there are no **new lines**

`shots="$(ls | grep -F "Screen Shot")"`

```
Screen Shot 2017-10-26 at 11.09.08 AM.png Screen Shot 2017-11-02 at 12.24.13 PM.png Screen Shot 2017-11-10 at 9.20.33 AM.png Screen Shot 2017-11-10 at 9.21.29 AM.png Screen Shot 2017-11-20 at 10.26.24 AM.png Screen Shot 2017-11-20 at 10.30.40 AM.png Screen Shot 2017-11-20 at 10.31.55 AM.png Screen Shot 2017-11-20 at 7.01.32 PM.png Screen Shot 2017-11-21 at 11.49.15 AM.png
```

1. How do I iterate over the screenshot entries and delete them?
2. How do I keep a newline on grep?

EDIT: Cyrus (see comment) has working answers to question 1. Still looking for question 2 answers for grep behavior

Comment: `rm Screen\ Shot\ *` or `rm "Screen Shot "*`?

Comment: @Cyrus thanks! That did work, however I will leave the question here as I am still interested in how grep is acting

Comment: Btw:: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: I suggest: `echo "$shots"`

Comment: @Cyrus echo "$shots" returns a list with no carriage returns, they are lost for some reason when I assign it to a var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still do this, you just need to specify the [`IFS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) (internal field separator).

```
shots="$(ls | grep -F "Screen Shot")"
echo $shots
>some_long_one_line_blob

IFS='$\n'
echo $shots
>line
>by
>line
>output
```

Or can you the `-E` argument to echo which will evaluate the newline characters.

```
echo -E "$shots"
>line
>by
>line
>output
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for :)

Comment: I like to use IFS you you are baking this into a script where you are using something like a for loop on each line of the output. I added a second example that I think would be a better solution to your issue?

Comment: The proper solution is to quote the string you `echo`.

Comment: Quotes are not the only solution. You also need the `-E` argument to echo to evaluate the `\n`.

Comment: Huh? The string will contain literal newlines, not the escape sequence `\n`; and `echo -E` is specifically to turn *off* the parsing of any such sequences.

Answer (score 1):

This was the right answer for me:

```
grep_result=`grep $pattern $searchfile`
echo "$grep_result"
```

produced the right echo output (cr-separated) when the $pattern was spread across multiple lines.